# The relationship between $\Gamma (a)$ and $\Gamma (a+\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: gamma-function

Does anybody know the relationship between the $\Gamma (a)$ and $\Gamma (a+\frac{1}{2})$? Is there an equation or an approximate equality between these two?

Comment: For integer $a$, [there are explicit formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function).

Comment: Did you see Wikipedia? $\Gamma(a) \Gamma(a+\frac{1}{2})=2^{1-2a}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2a)$, which leads a nice relationship if $a$ be an integer.

Comment: @Shahrooz Janbaz Thank you very much! But if $\alpha $ is not a integer, it's a fraction, is this equation still valid?

Comment: Yes! see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function.